# IE8 Report Viewer columns are too wide

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, rdlc, reportviewer2008

Hi I am currently using Visual Studio 2008 report viewer. When I view the page in firefox or chrome, the column widths match the size of the content. When I view the page in IE8 the column widths are about 3 times as wide as the content.

I have checked my CSS and there is nothing that should interfere with the report rendering.

Is there a way to correct this in IE8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can find in my (rather old) code, there are two things related to IE8 / report width :

- in the head of the page

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
  ```
- in the ReportViewer tag :

  ```
   <rsweb:ReportViewer ... SizeToReportContent="true"/>
  ```

Hope this will help